# Windows CPP InjectSyntheticPointerInput

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm trying to make a pen simulator using the win32 (Winuser.h) InjectSyntheticPointerInput API to allow me to simulate Pen Pressure and other sensors.
But when I try to Inject the input, it gives me an error code (87: The parameter is incorrect)... My code so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>;

#include <Windows.h>;
#include <errhandlingapi.h>;
#include <Winuser.h>;

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    // Init pointer
    const HSYNTHETICPOINTERDEVICE pointer = CreateSyntheticPointerDevice(PT_PEN, 1, POINTER_FEEDBACK_INDIRECT);
    
    if (pointer == nullptr) {
        const DWORD err = GetLastError();
        
        std::cout << "Pointer: Error code " << err << std::endl;
        return err;
    }

    // Input creation
    POINTER_TYPE_INFO inputInfo[1];

    inputInfo[0].type = PT_PEN;
    inputInfo[0].penInfo.pointerInfo.pointerType = PT_PEN;
    inputInfo[0].penInfo.pointerInfo.pointerId = 0;
    inputInfo[0].penInfo.pointerInfo.frameId = 0;
    inputInfo[0].penInfo.pointerInfo.pointerFlags = POINTER_FLAG_INRANGE | POINTER_FLAG_INCONTACT | POINTER_FLAG_DOWN;
    inputInfo[0].penInfo.penMask = PEN_MASK_PRESSURE | PEN_MASK_TILT_X | PEN_MASK_TILT_Y;

    inputInfo[0].penInfo.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x = 200;
    inputInfo[0].penInfo.pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y = 200;
    inputInfo[0].penInfo.pressure = 1024;
    inputInfo[0].penInfo.tiltX = 15;
    inputInfo[0].penInfo.tiltY = -26;

    // Inject input
    if (!InjectSyntheticPointerInput(pointer, inputInfo, 1))
    {
        const DWORD err = GetLastError();

        std::cout << "Input: Error code " << err << std::endl;
        return err;
    }

    // Destroy pointer
    DestroySyntheticPointerDevice(pointer);
}
```

When I open with the debugger the pointer has a value of 0x00000000000000b4 it isn't null, but is it normal to have so low memory address? Is that the problem with my code?

I also appreciate if you could point me to code snippets or better explanations than the official microsoft documentation regarding this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following https://github.com/gsbischoff/usb-pen-injection/blob/master/PenClient.c
lines 126 and 127

```cpp
        // These bastards apparently must be zero
        PointerInfo.penInfo.pointerInfo.dwTime = 0;
        PointerInfo.penInfo.pointerInfo.PerformanceCount = 0;
```

Comment: Is this an answer? It doesn't appear to have much rationale to go by. Why would those values need to be zero, rather than, say, have another well defined value?

Comment: I also don't know, but when I putted this values, it worked, I just didn't marked as the answer because of "You can accept your own answer in 2 days" (I created the account today), but I will try with another values

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-pointer_info) explains the rules for passing in timestamps. While passing 0 for either is certainly within those rules, there's no strict requirement for them to be 0. *"If both `dwTime` and `PerformanceCount` are specified in `InjectTouchInput`, `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` is returned."* describes the error you observed in your question.